# getting the module and line that a function was called from

Tags: python

Is there a way to programatically get the line number and name of a function?

For example, I want to pass a list of strings to a function :

```
s = [calling_module, calling_function, line_number]
report(s)
```

Currently I just put it all in manually :

```
s = ["module abc", "func()", "line 22", "notes"]
report(s)
```

But I would like to know if there is an automatic way for python to fill in the module name (I think __name__ does that), function name and line number for me. Is there a way?

Comment: While there are legitimate use cases for this (error reporting, or implementing things like Python 3's `super()`), think long and hard about whether you really need this information before using it. This violates the normal flow of information in a program, and it can make your code much more confusing if you overuse it.

Comment: Using it to inspect other code, to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`inspect`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html) module functions. For example,

```
import inspect

def b():
    f = inspect.currentframe()
    current = inspect.getframeinfo(f)
    caller = inspect.getframeinfo(f.f_back)
    #caller = inspect.getframeinfo(inspect.getouterframes(f)[1][0])
    print(__name__, current.filename, current.function, current.lineno, caller.function)

def a():
    b()

a()
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want something along the lines of `traceback.extract_stack()`:

```
>>> def test():
...   print "In Function"
...   print traceback.extract_stack()
...
>>>
>>> test()
In Function
[('<stdin>', 1, '<module>', None), ('<stdin>', 3, 'test', None)]
```

Though the results would need to be parsed.

Answer (score 0):

```
from inspect import currentframe, getframeinfo, getmodulename

def report():
    f = getframeinfo(currentframe().f_back)
    print getmodulename(f.filename), f.lineno, f.function
```

Note that using

```
__name__
```

will return the name of the module containing report, while the code above will show the name of the module that called report.